# Markdown Create multiple links with common prefix efficiently

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown, readme

Let's say I want to create following links in my `markdown` document:

- https://github.com/kaushal02/CP/search?q=_QueryString
- https://github.com/kaushal02/CP/search?q=_AnotherQueryString
- https://github.com/kaushal02/CP/search?q=_YetAnotherQueryString

Since all of these links has a common prefix, is there a way to create a rule so that when I pass an argument, say **QueryString** then it creates a link "https://github.com/kaushal02/CP/search?q=_QueryString"?

Also, is there a way to suppress link creation when we write a text which is a valid http-link?

Comment: What Markdown processor are you using? There is no way to do this using standard Markdown, and standard Markdown doesn't automatically link text links. Maybe you're using GitHub Flavored Markdown?

Comment: @Chris yes actually this is particularly required for my main readme in one of the GitHub repos